# What goes into the context parameter of YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent (*context*, YTapiKey, videoID)?

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube-api

I'm writing an app, and want the app to play a YouTube video using the YouTube API. What do I put in the context parameter of YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent (*context*, YTapiKey, videoID)?

The documentation says that the context should be an activity. I've tried MainActivity, and activity_main, and findViewById<>(R.layout.activity_main). None of them works.

the MainActivity.kt file:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(context, YTapiKey, videoID)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

the activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="com.vcsw.explicacao.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtubePlayerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I expected that simply placing the name of the activity in the context parameter of the intent YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(*context*, YTapiKey, videoID) would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: for context use `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is in an activity. To refer to the activity instance, use `this` keyword for an activity context.